# Angular: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null" while using Slick Slider

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, foreach

I'm using Slick Slider(https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick) to show a horizontal slider at the bottom of my webpage:

```
    <div class="container" ng-if="schedule.length>0">
      <div class="row">
        <slick dots="true" init-onload="true" data="schedule" center-mode="false" infinite="false" speed="300" slides-to-show="4" touch-move="true" slides-to-scroll="1" class="slider one-time">
          <div ng-repeat="x in schedule">
            <div class="status-x-current">
              <a class="x-button" ng-if="x.title == ''" data-ng-click="showRes(workplace, x)">Click here to to do something</a>
              <h3 ng-if="x.title != ''" id = "x_title1" class="x-slider-title">Titel: {{x.title}}</h3>
              <h3 ng-if="x.title != ''" id = "x_time1" class="x-slider-time">{{x.date}}</h3>
          </div>
          </div>
        </slick>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This works fine at the beginning when the page is (re)loaded, but the datasource "schedule" gets updated from server every minute and after "schedule" is updated I get the following error and the button doesn't work:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null
    at angular.js?body=1:3851
    at forEach (angular.js?body=1:304)
    at Object.$AnimateProvider.$get.enter (angular.js?body=1:3850)
    at angular.js?body=1:18726
    at publicLinkFn (angular.js?body=1:5421)
    at ngRepeatAction (angular.js?body=1:18724)
    at Object.$watchCollectionAction [as fn] (angular.js?body=1:11300)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js?body=1:11396)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js?body=1:11635)
    at done (angular.js?body=1:7636)(anonymous function) @ angular.js?body=1:9038$get @ angular.js?body=1:6649$get.Scope.$digest @ angular.js?body=1:11408$get.Scope.$apply @ angular.js?body=1:11635done @ angular.js?body=1:7636completeRequest @ angular.js?body=1:7802xhr.onreadystatechange @ angular.js?body=1:7758
```

If I remove the "slick" tack from the html code, the issues doesn't occur anymore, so I has something to do with Slick, but I'm not sure what the exact problem is and how to solve it.

Comment: Can you provide me some part of that 3851 code? Probably i can trace that problem by source. At least, for answering question we are missing your controller's code. Probably point of interest is your updating method or response of server with some invalid value (such as null).

Comment: This is a part of the code on line 3851:   forEach(element, function(node) {
          parentNode.insertBefore(node, afterNextSibling);
        });, but that's angular code not mine. I have tested the response from server and it's always exactly the same JSON file, no differents at all. I don't think its caused by the server returning invalid value because it works fine when I don't use slick slider.

Comment: Oh, I remembered - in my case when I used `ui-grid` the `null` had place when I was using custom template and forgot to add required `class` to some `element` that was used as `parentNode`. I guess you simply missing some definition of needed `selector` that is used to find that `parentNode`. Please trace what and when actually `parentNode` takes it's place and if it does not help - take some code example and run debug there, so you will find out what actually is that `parentNode`

Comment: Hi, I found the reason for the error. It because of "init-onload="true" data="schedule"".  It doesn't like it when my controller assigns other value to schedule. If I remove those lines, I don't get the error but everytime schedule is updated the divs "status-x-current" are added vertically beneath each other instead of horizontally next to each other. I don't know the solution.

Comment: Doing that makes slick behave weirdly. It removes the space between the status-x-current divs after schedule is updated.

Answer (score 1):

I was joking about `float`. Add `ng-if='ctrl.isDataLoaded'` to your block, so it will init only after your `controller` will acquire proper data. That should fix your problem of missing data actually until it is useful.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Which block are you referring to, and how do I know when the data is fully loaded? schedule gets it's value at first webpage load and gets updated after that at a fixed interval, so it's always fully loaded after the first page load. I did try setting a boolean false before retrieving the data from server and setting it to true after the data is retrieved and using the boolean in the ng-if but that didn't work.

Comment: Also it seems that the error always occurs after schedule is reloaded exactly 3 times. So the first three times schedule gets new data assigned from the server the error doesn't occur. After 3 times I get the error. And I checked if schedule's value is fine or not after it's reloaded 3 times, and it seems fine.

Comment: So you do something like `then((response) => { ... $scope.schedule = response ... })`?

Comment: This is what I'm doing: (function tick() {
      ScheduleService.getSchedule({}, function(response) {
          $scope.schedule = response.schedule;
          $timeout(tick, 10000);
      });

  })();

Comment: Try to add watcher for schedule so you will see every time it changed. I had something like that coz not me directly were changing data but directive.